# Merge tags [hp-quality-center], [quality-center], [alm], and 2 more

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

*([Copying over from meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212091/193893), with numbers updated.)*

These tags refer to [the](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hp-quality-center/info) [same](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quality-center/info) [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qc/info): HP Quality Center. They should be merged into one / have the others be synonyms for **[hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center)** aka HPQC, which is the least ambiguous, though not historically accurate (see item #4 below).

- [quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center) has 149 questions, created 3 years ago
- [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center) has 112 question, created 12 months ago
- [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) has 149 questions, created 2 years ago
- [testdirector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testdirector)  [also exists](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/testdirector/info) with just 5 questions - Mercury's Test Director was bought by HP and re-branded to Quality Center. (And to-date, we still see 'TDD' in the APIs.)

HP Application Lifecycle Management ("ALM"; *terrible name*) v11 and v12, which just happen to be the ones to come after Quality Center 10, includes Quality Center as well some other enterprise tools. If `[hp-alm]` or `[hpqc]` tags get created in the future, those should also point to [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center) - in the context of StackOverflow questions, those would be the same as HPQC.

The tag [alm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alm): has 131 questions, created 3 years ago. On the most recent questions, it's about HP ALM but questions prior to Oct 2013 are about "application lifecycle management" as a term, not the HP tool.

After the rename/merge of the four tags mentioned, [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) could optionally be burninated.

Related: Read the comments on the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212091/193893) for the previous discussion.

Comment: Is there a reason that this hasn't gotten any action? These tags are clearly all referring to the same thing.

Comment: There is a user going through all of these tags and adding `hp-quality-center` via suggested edits.

Comment: Yup, lots of tag edits from a user right now.

Answer (score 1):

So there seems to be 4 tags here which are needed to be synonymized, let's go through them one by one:

- [quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center): This was synonymized to [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center) and merged a few years back, so now, we're good.
- [testdirector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testdirector): I went through the 5 questions and it did seem like they were all about HP Quality Center, so I went ahead and added it as a synonym.
- [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc): <s>This is something which I'm unsure of. The tag name is just "QC" and could have been mistaken with something else. Out of the 250 questions tagged [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc), I could refine out this [list of 50 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqc%5D+-%5Bhp-quality-center%5D+is%3Aq+-%22Quality+Center%22+-%22HP%22+-%22ALM%22+-%22VAPI%22&mixed=0) which might not be related to [quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center). If you can quickly go through those 50 posts, and remove the [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) from those that are incorrectly tagged, then I can go ahead and merge the [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) tag to [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center).</s> TylerH has gone through the list of posts tagged [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) and removed the tags from those that weren't about HP Quality Center, so now I've added [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) as a synonym for [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center).

Comment: HP Quality Center is actually called Micro Focus Quality Center now, it seems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Focus_Quality_Center - we may need to create a new tag for that and then synonymize HPQC to it.

Comment: PS, you can further refine your list by using this list instead (added some tags that always indicate QC means the HP / Micro Focus QC) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bqc%5D+-%5Bhp-quality-center%5D+-%5Bota%5D+-%5Bqtp%5D+-%5Balm%5D+is%3Aq+-%22Quality+Center%22+-%22HP%22+-%22ALM%22+-%22VAPI%22

Comment: I have gone through your list and removed the QC tag from the few questions that weren't about this subject. The tag is now ready to be synonymized.

Comment: Thanks, I'll create the synonym now.